# How do I figure out how to call Sotlayer Service API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How could I figure out what to pass as inputs for the various SoftLayer Services?

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Group/getAttachedVolumes

I know how to create the objects to call these commands, but it's unclear what to pass into these API references. Am I missing some sort of documentation or is there a discrete way to figure it out?

Up until now I have basically been guessing and looking at how the managers call related functions, but in this case, no manager uses this service or particular function.

Comment: In this case you need to see the required headers, in this particular case the documentation says : initParameter and autenticación. The init para meter is basically the id of the object you want to get,edit or delete. Using python you pasa the id like this: clent.getAttachedVolumes(id=111) regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looked manager using python, take a look this script to **getAttachedVolumes**:

```
"""
This script retrieve the network storage volumes this group is attached to

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Group/getAttachedVolumes
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

storageGroupId = 448757
# declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Group'].getAttachedVolumes(id=storageGroupId)
    pprint.pprint(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

I hope that it will provide an idea how to send the inputs for the method, you should send in this lineL

> client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Group'].getAttachedVolumes(id=storageGroupId)

Take a look the following links to get more information:

- [SoftLayer API Python
  Client](http://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client/)
- [Python](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python)
- [Going Further with the SoftLayer API Python Client - Part 1](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1)

Another important links:

- [Getting Started](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/getting-started)
- [Using Initialization Parameters in the SoftLayer API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-initialization-parameters-softlayer-api)

For other programming languages:

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)

Please let me know if you need further assistance with other method, programming language or doubt about it.

> **Updated**

To retrieve an account's Network Storage groups(with their identifiers ), you can use this method: [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorageGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorageGroups), below an example in python:

```
"""
This script retrieves an account's Network Storage Groups

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorageGroups
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkStorageGroups()
    pprint.pprint(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

You will retrieve the identifiers (**groupId**) in the response

Comment: Great response here, I don't see much on groups though. Would you know how to get a the groupID?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to attach the script to get NetworkStorageGroups, please see **Updated** section in my response. Please, let me know if you have any doubt or issue